# Javascript animation only loading once per page

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have an SVG, animated wavy line. I'd like these wavy lines to appear multiple times on a certain page. However, only the first instance seems to show and the others don't... I know this because if I delete the first one in the inspector, the next one displays.

Here's my code:

```js
let xs = []
for (var i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
  xs.push(i)
}

let t = 0

function animatewavy() {
  
  let points = xs.map(x => {
    
    let y = 10 + 2 * Math.sin((x + t) / 5)
    
    return [x, y]
  })
  
  let path = "M" + points.map(p => {
    return p[0] + "," + p[1]
  }).join(" L")
  
  document.querySelector("path").setAttribute("d", path)
  
  t += 0.8
  
  requestAnimationFrame(animatewavy)
}

animatewavy()
```

```css
.wavy-line {
  margin:35px auto;
  width:150px;
}

.wavy-line svg {
  height: 15px;
  width:150px;
}

.wavy-line path {
  stroke-width: 5px;
  fill: none;
}

.wavy-line .path-green { stroke: #56AE5F; }
.wavy-line .path-blue { stroke: #1FB5D1; }
.wavy-line .path-yellow { stroke: #F9B930; }
```

```html
<div class="wavy-line"><svg><path class="path-blue"></path></svg></div>

<div class="wavy-line"><svg><path class="path-blue"></path></svg></div>

<div class="wavy-line"><svg><path class="path-blue"></path></svg></div>

<div class="wavy-line"><svg><path class="path-blue"></path></svg></div>
```

You'll see the first one appearing but the rest of them not... Im not sure what im doing wrong, do I need to somehow end the javascript and restart it?

I'd appreciate any help possible :)

Comment: you need to have a loop, actually your code `document.querySelector("path")` will only target the first one. You need to iterate it of all other paths

Comment: you might want to try `document.querySelectorAll("path")` instead of `document.querySelector("path")`

Comment: Hi again Temani!! Ah ok, a loop in my javascript, I assume... sorry to blatantly ask you how...  but could you guide me in the right direction about how to do this?

Comment: Sorry deterjan - making that change doesn't seem to work at all, it just stops all of them from displaying

Comment: well, `querySelectorAll` returns an array that you have to iterate over, so the line becomes `document.querySelectorAll("path").forEach(elem => elem.setAttribute("d", path))`

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, I'm really new with JS, I would have never figured that out, but I can see how that works now. It works perfectly thank you! :) If you want to add it as an answer I'll mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector("path")` returns only the first match, that's why only the first svg is animating.

To animate all svg's at once, get all `path` nodes as an array using `document.querySelectorAll` and iterate over them to call `setAttribute` on each one like so:

`document.querySelectorAll("path").forEach(elem => elem.setAttribute("d", path))`

Answer (score 1):

change the document.querySelector() to the document.querySelectorAll()

or

better still u can iterate the containers to fix ur animations in.

Comment: Thanks for this Daniel! Unfortunately making this change and adding 'All' breaks the whole thing and none of them work. What do you mean with your second option?

Comment: Loop through the <path> tag like this: let myPath = document.getElementsByTagName("path"); for(x in myPath){ myPath[x].setAttribute("d", path)}